# Swift enum values are not accessible

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, enums

I have following class with enum defined in it:

```
public class MyError: NSError {

    public enum Type: Int {
        case ConnectionError
        case ServerError
    }

    init(type: Type) {
        super.init(domain: "domain", code: type.rawValue, userInfo: [:])
    }
}
```

When I try to check the error later in my tests like:

```
expect(error.code).to(equal(MyError.Type.ConnectionError.rawValue))
```

I get the compilation error: `Type MyError.Type has no member ConnectionError`

Any ideas what I am doing wrong here?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The problem is that `Type` is a Swift keyword and your custom `Type` confuses the compiler.

In my tests in a Playground your code generated the same error. The solution is to change `Type` for any other name. Example with `Kind`:

```
public enum Kind: Int {
    case ConnectionError
    case ServerError
}

init(type: Kind) {
    super.init(domain: "domain", code: type.rawValue, userInfo: [:])
}
```

Then

```
MyError.Kind.ConnectionError.rawValue
```

works as expected.

Comment: Thanks. That works for me as well.

Answer (score 2):

The problem with your `enum` is its name: Swift uses `.Type` to access type:

```
if childMirror.valueType is String.Type {  
  println("property is of type String")
}
```

Renaming it to something else will fix the problem.